# How to rotate the projectile based on where the user clicks the mouse in c++

Tags: c++, sfml

Right now I have a player that i want to shoot a projectile every time the mouse is clicked. But depending on where the mouse is clicked, I want the projectile to rotate so that it appears that the projectile is always going straight out from the player. I am using sfml.

This checks if the mouse is clicked:

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)){
        projectile.fire();
}
```

which works fine, my problem is getting the rotation correct and getting the projectile to travel towards the mouse slowly and not teleporting there instantly, so basically the whole projectile.fire method.

Here is whats in my projectile.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Entity.h"

class Projectile : public Entity {
public:
    void fire() { 

    }


};
```

Not much because it inherits from Entity.h so here is Entity.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

class Entity {
public:
    int x, y;
    int speed = 1;

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Rect<float> size = sprite.getGlobalBounds();

    void disappear() {
        sprite.setPosition(-10, 0);
    }

    void setOriginToCenter() { // NEED TO FIX
        sprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(size.width / 2, size.height / 2));
    }

    void setOrigin(float x, float y) {
        sprite.setOrigin(x, y);
    }

    sf::Vector2f getOrigin() {
        return sprite.getOrigin();
    }

    void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    sf::Vector2f getPosition() {
        return sprite.getPosition();
    }

    void setScale(float xscale, float yscale) {
        sprite.setScale(xscale, yscale);
    }

    void move(int ax, int ay) {
        sf::Vector2f position = getPosition();
        position.x += ax * speed;
        position.y += ay * speed;
        sprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
    }

};
```

I'm not sure if I explained the problem well or provided enough code / information, so please do tell me if that is the case.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Which function you need to rotate or by how much you have to rotate (i assume in radians)?

Comment: I'm trying to get a projectile to fire from the player (which moves with wasd) when the left mouse button is clicked and the rotation of the projectile to be set so it always looks like the projectile is firing straight from the player, no matter where the user clicks on the screen. I want the fire method to do all of it, determine the rotation and make the projectile travel to where the mouse is clicked. Hopefully this clears it up, sorry if it doesn't, I don't know another way to explain it.

Comment: I got that, but I'm not sure exactly what you're struggling with: How to rotate a sprite in SFML? (I don't know that either) How to compute the required angle? (You best use std::atan2 for that) Or how to slowly move an object? (You would probably best add a virtual update(float elapsed_time) method to entity, which you call once every iteration from the main loop and overload for projectiles)

Comment: Yes, I am having trouble with both of those issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the required rotation like this:

```
#include <cmath>
float radians = std::atan2(buttonClickX, buttonClickY);
```

Most likely SFML now provides a function to rotate the sprite e.g.

```
sprite.rotate(radians);
```

You have to look up the documentation for thr exact function name.

Comment: Either that doesn't work or apply what you said to my code incorrectly. 
Projectile.h: 
#pragma once
#include "Entity.h"
#include <cmath>

class Projectile : public Entity {
public:
 void fire(sf::Vector2i mouseposition) { 
  float radians = std::atan2(mouseposition.x,mouseposition.y);
  sprite.rotate(radians);
 }


};

(1/2)

Comment: main.cpp (the part thats relevant):
// fires the projectile if the button is clicked

  if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)){
   projectile.setPosition(player1position.x, player1position.y);
   sf::Vector2i mouseposition = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
   projectile.fire(mouseposition);
  }

(2/2)

Comment: Sorry I know its hard on the eyes but I don't know how else to show you what I have.

Comment: Right now, instead of changing the rotation of the projectile to match where the user clicked the mouse, it just rotates it further in a circle.

Comment: "sprite.rotate()" modifies the amount of rotation by the amount given. To set a specific and explicit amount of rotation, use "sprite.setRotation()".